# VHDL- Pseudo Random Number Generating with Seed using linear equation?

Tags: vhdl

I'm having trouble writing a random number sequence generator in VHDL.
I tried to use a linear equation to do so, but the Xilinx compiler keeps complaining about the syntax.

The code uses a clock input and the board has 7 switches that will be used to enter the seed. From there, it's all algebra. Or so I hoped.

The code I have is the following:

```
entity RandNumSeqGen is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           switches: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
           num : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 3));
end RandNumSeqGen;

architecture Behavioral of RandNumSeqGen is
constant M : integer := 278200;
constant A : integer := 6521;
constant B : integer := 88977; 
variable rand_f: real :=0.0;
variable rand_d: integer :=0;
variable seed: integer :=0;
seed <= to_integer(signed(switches));

begin
if (clk'event and clk='1') then
    Seed := (seed*A+B) mod M;
    rand_f:=seed/real(M);
    rand_f:=rand_f*1000;
    rand_d:=integer(rand_f) mod 12;
    num<= rand_d;
end if;


end Behavioral;
```

The code would ideally keep on making a new random number between 0 and 11 and write it in the num output.

The error report has, well, a lot to say.

Maybe there is a problem with how I declared the variables?
If you know what needs fixing, please let me know. I want to learn to do better.

```
Line 47: Syntax error near "seed".
Line 50: Syntax error near "then".
Line 51: Syntax error near "mod".
Line 52: Syntax error near ":=".
Line 53: Syntax error near ":=".
Line 54: Syntax error near "mod".
Line 56: Syntax error near "if".
ERROR:ProjectMgmt - 7 error(s) found while parsing design hierarchy.
```

Sorry for the noob question, I've just gotten started with VHDL numeric variables. Up until now I've only used C and Python

Comment: Where is line 47 in a 26 line example? Also, you may want to try a different VHDL compiler; a good one will tell you what the syntax error is. For example, "cannot use variable assignment to a signal", "no overloaded division operator between integer and real", or "if/then cannot be used outside a Process statement" to name three I can see.

Comment: Yes, VHDL has variables, but what you want to use are signals. So please consult a textbook or some online media and read about VHDL and signals. Type real is not synthesizable.

Comment: A lot of syntax errors in this code. You should start looking for a VHDL tutorial and such. VHDL is not a CPU language like C, Java, etc.

Comment: In addition to the syntax errors you could note that  type REAL, mod m nor mod 12 are synthesis eligible. UG901 (Vivado Design Suite Synthesis), Ch. 5, VHDL Constructs Support Status. You'd need a reset or a load to load the seed from switches.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should probably be

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity RandNumSeqGen is
    Port (
        clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
        switches: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
        num : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 3)
    );
end entity;

architecture Behavioral of RandNumSeqGen is
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    constant M : integer := 278200;
    constant A : integer := 6521;
    constant B : integer := 88977;
begin
    gen_rand_out: process(clk)
        variable rand_f: real := 0.0;
        variable rand_d: integer := 0;
        variable seed: integer := 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            -- seed := to_integer(signed(switches)); -- I don't get what you want to do here
            seed := (seed*A+B) mod M;
            rand_f := real(seed)/real(M);
            rand_f := rand_f*1000.0;
            rand_d := integer(rand_f) mod 12;
            num <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(rand_d, num'length));
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

But this will of course not synthesize...